# Amazon ec2 instance creation issue

Tags: amazon-ec2

i have created Amazon ec2 instance.

while trying to login using key(.ppk) file, It giving error, saying: **server refusing key file**

and **No supported authentication methods available**

i am using username as, ec2-user.

can anybody help me ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to login via ssh without the key. You need to generate a key pair, send the public key to the instance (via the web interface), and then connect with ssh using the private key.